# XNA project stops working out of the blue

Tags: deployment, build, xna, visual-studio-debugging

Last time I worked on my XNA project about a week ago it was running fine, the last thing I did was deploy it to the XBox for a demo. Now, after no changes, for some reason it won't build an I am getting the following error:

> Unable to copy file "E:\Prototype2\DebugView XNA\bin\x86\Debug\Content\font.xnb" to "bin\x86\Debug\font.xnb". The device is not ready.
>       Windows Copy of Prototype2**

I have checked this path and there is no folder in that path called Content and no font.xnb file. I have no idea why it would suddenly have trouble in this way or why it wants this file.

Comment: Are you compiling to a removable drive? Make sure you have the rights to do those actions, maybe start VS with admin rights. But I'd go for a "headshot" and just move the whole project to another location. Recreating the project might be an overkill, but it usually never fails.

Comment: thank you, yes its on a thumb drive, i will try this